# how to show zero when IN does not return any value sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to return 0 when no rows found for this following condition.

```
SELECT P.externalid,
       Count(DISTINCT Pp.patientuid) patcount
FROM   PatientProcedure Pp (nolock )
       INNER JOIN visit Temp (nolock )
               ON Temp.patientuid = Pp.patientuid
                  AND (Pp.effectivedate = Temp.VisitDate)
                  AND Temp.RenderringProviderUid = Pp.serviceprovideruid
                  AND Temp.VisitDate >= '07-01-2013'
                  AND Temp.VisitDate <= '06-30-2014'
       INNER JOIN serviceprovider Sp (nolock )
               ON Pp.serviceprovideruid = Sp.serviceprovideruid
                  AND Sp.inactive = 0
       INNER JOIN MasterCode Mc (nolock )
               ON Mc.codeuid = Pp.procedurecodeuid
       INNER JOIN MasterCodeSet Mcs (nolock )
               ON Mcs.Value = Mc.code
       INNER JOIN practice P
               ON P.PracticeUid = Temp.practiceuid
WHERE  NAME = 'Visual_Field_Exam'
       AND Temp.mastervisittypeuid IS NOT NULL
       AND P.ExternalID IN ('26900', '26902', '26903', '26906',
                            '26907', '26908', '26946', '26963',
                            '27128', '27131', '27133', '27134',
                            '27135', '27137', '27166', '27167',
                            '27497', '27498', '27499', '27501',
                            '27502', '27504', '27505', '27509',
                            '27510', '27511', '27518')
GROUP  BY P.ExternalID
```

I have found patient count for many practices but no patient found for one practice. So, I want to return count(patientuid) = 0 for that practice.

Here is the sample data.

```
PracticeId  Patcount
26900   2583
26902   826
26903   4085
26906   241
26907   3205
26908   4592
26946   344
26963   398
27128   238
27131   2467
27133   975
27135   815
27137   1252
27166   1038
27167   211
27497   1053
27498   934
27499   3467
27501   617
27502   3511
27504   7222
27505   683
27509   210
27510   1145
27511   181
27518   500
```

In above output I got data for 26 practices, but "27134" practice does not having patient count, so i want it show 0.

I want above output. How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Something smells about this query - aside from the fact that it doesn't work without a `GROUP BY` - why does the `Patient` table contain both a `PracticeId` **and** the `PracticeName`?

Comment: Hello Damien, I have edited my query here. Previous one was just sample query.

Comment: Can you include sample data? You can also use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) to show your problem in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a table `Practicer` which holds the practicers (i do not know if that is the correct word, but doesn't matter for SQL). Then you need to left join that table with `Patient` in order to get a list of all Practicers filter by you where clause. So this will get the ones you want.

```
Select PR.PracticeName, 
       count(distinct patientid) 
from   Practicer PR
       LEFT JOIN Patient P
           ON PR.Practiceid = P.Practiceid
where  PR.Practiceid in
       ('12345','65478','78541')
GROUP BY PR.PracticeName
```

In general, you want to return 2 fields. The first is the list of `Hospitals`, `Practiotioners` or whatever else you may like. In order to get the full list (even if it does not have a count) you need to start with that table.

Lets say we have a table `Hospitals` that we want to filter on specific ids. The we would have the following query:

```
SELECT  HospitalId, 
        HospitalName
FROM    Hospitals
WHERE   HospitalId IN ('26900', '26902', '26903')
```

Now we would like to know the no of patients in each hospital. We know that hospital with id '26902' has no patients (WOW). If we would go to the `Patients` table and tried the following:

```
SELECT   HospitalId, 
         COUNT(*) AS NoOfPatients
FROM     Patients
WHERE    HospitalId IN ('26900', '26902', '26903')
GROUP BY HospitalId
```

It would return only ids '26900' and '26903' as the Hospital with id '26902' does not have any patient.

So, how do we figure out the third Hospital?

We join the two tables:

```
SELECT   H.HospitalId, 
         COUNT(PatienId) AS NoOfPatients
FROM     Hospitals H
         LEFT JOIN Patients P
WHERE    H.HospitalId IN ('26900', '26902', '26903')
GROUP BY H.HospitalId
```

Now this would return all the requested hospitals with the according number of patients.

Your case is more complex, as we need more joins from the `Hospitals` to the `Patients` tables. But i hope my explanation will get you on the right track.

The essence of it is to start from your List Table to your Count table.

Comment: Aren't you missing the JOIN condition here?

Comment: It is quite unclear. Which is the table that holds the names of the Practicioners (<--was that the right word???)

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos : Here is not important to hold name of practice or practictioners. I just want Patient Count for Specific practices (Hospitals). And I got count for that but i want to return 0 if specific practice does not getting patient count.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos : Thanks. Your explanation will get on right track. Let me try it. I will inform you once it is done.